# Missing php_apcu.dll for PHP 8.2 / APCu 5.1.22?

Tags: php, apc, apcu

I am trying to set up **PHP 8.2** with **APCu** extension on **Windows**.

However, it seems that **PHP 8.2** compatibility was only added to the latest **APCu** version **5.1.22** (released 2022-09-19), and the corresponding `php_apcu.dll` file is missing - I cannot find it at neither location:

- https://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/apcu/
- https://pecl.php.net/package/APCu/5.1.22/windows

When I try using the previous APCu version **5.1.21**, I get the following error:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: apcu: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20210902
PHP    compiled with module API=20220829
These options need to match
```

Should I downgrade my PHP installation to **8.1.x** then?

Comment: It is noted in this thread (https://github.com/krakjoe/apcu/issues/450) that you can allegedly download them from the CI artifacts, but I don't know the specifics of that

Comment: APCu dll file is not yet available. (Imagick either).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks **Chris Haas**! Following your [GitHub link](https://github.com/krakjoe/apcu/issues/450), I was able to download `apcu-8.2-x64-ts.zip` file that contains `php_apcu.dll` compatible with **PHP 8.2**. Please note, however, that this is an artifact of **APCu 5.1.23-dev**, not the latest stable release **5.1.22**...

Comment: You can use https://github.com/krakjoe/apcu/releases/tag/v5.1.23

Answer (score 2):

For some reason, the [official download page](https://pecl.php.net/package/APCu/5.1.22/windows) does not have the required Windows binaries for APCu 5.1.22 Stable, nor does the [download folder](https://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/apcu/5.1.22/) exist.

The GitHub issue referenced in the currently accepted answer provided download links to the compiled binaries for some time, but they have since all expired. And as mentioned, they were for the 5.1.23-dev version anyway, not 5.1.22 Stable.

Therefore we decided to compile the Windows binaries for APCu 5.1.22 and the different PHP versions and architectures ourselves and make them available here:
https://www.48design.com/en/news/2023/10/06/php_apcu-dll-5.1.22-windows-binaries-php-8.2/#download

Should the need arise, we might update this for upcoming versions of APCu.